# Variable isn't storing return value

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that converts a hex string into decimal.  However I am having an issue assigning a returned integer value from the findLength function.  Going by the printf statements I can tell that findLength(theString) will yield the correct value however length is showing a value of 0 despite the fact that I have length = findlength(theString).

This isn't a homework problem, I'm just absolutely stumped as to why this simple assignment isn't working.  I've already declared length so I know that's not the issue.  I'm also getting no compiler messages.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I know convert doesn't do anything useful and the for loop needs to be fixed however that shouldn't be effecting the findLength return right? 
Second Edit:
I've always submitted a string of '324' to be tested.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int convert(char s[], int theLength);
int findLength(char s[]);

int main(){
    char theString[100];
    int result;
    int i;
    int length;


    printf("%s","Hello, please enter a string below.  Press enter when finished.");


    scanf("%s",theString);      //Apparently scanf is bad but we'll learn better input methods later.
                               //For my tests I submitted a string of '324'.  

    length = (findLength(theString));     //length = findLength('324')
    printf("%d",findLength(theString));   //yields 3
    printf("%d",length);                  //yields value of 0 always.

    result  = convert(theString, length);
    printf("%d\n result is",result);

    return 0;

}               //End of main

int convert(char s[], int theLength){       //This function will eventually converts a string of hex into ints.  As of now it does nothing useful.
    int i;
    int sum;


    for(i = theLength; i=0; i--){
        sum = sum + s[i];
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }

    return sum;
}               //End of convert



int findLength(char s[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i]!='\0'; ++i){
    }

    return(i);

}               //End of findLength
```

Comment: `i=0` - Something tells me you didn't mean for that to be your for-loop conditional. Turn up your warning levels. And if you're set on enumerating that backwards, it should read `for(i=theLength; i--;)`

Comment: Yes convert needs to be fixed but the problem I'm having isn't related to the convert function.  I'm wondering why the return value of findLength isn't stored to the int length variable.

Comment: It would help immensely if you actually included the input string *verbatim* that you're testing with. After addressing that mentioned above, [see it live](http://ideone.com/T6nOgH). Also fix your indeterminate initial value of `sum`

Comment: why extra in printf ?     printf("%s","Hello, please enter a string below.  Press enter when finished.");.

Comment: what's your compiler the code works https://ideone.com/cpi2C9. just initialize first value as 0 for `sum` and change `for(i = theLength; i=0; 0<=i; i--)`

Comment: I used the GNU GCC Compiler.  I tried it at first in the terminal and then with codeblocks.  Also what's wrong with the initial value of sum?  I thought all int variables had a value of 0 by default no?  Should I set it to int sum = 0;

Comment: of course no. you must initialize as `0` if you want. You should read some c book. Previous answer I thought i deleted `i=0`; , it would be deleted. @theBigDream

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname I wasn't aware.  I just started reading K and R.  Does that mean that I have to initialize my other variables = to 0?  Such as result, and length?

Comment: not for all. if you want first value to `0` or something else you must initialize like `sum` otherwise no. When you do more exercises you will understand

Answer (score 2):

The variable `length` is storing the correct value. I think what has you confused is how you've laid out your `printf` statements. If you were to try something like the below it would be much easier to see that your code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findLength(char s[]);

int main(){
    char theString[100];
    int result;
    int i;
    int length;

    printf("Hello, please enter a string below. Press enter when finished.\n");

    scanf("%s",theString);

    length = (findLength(theString));
    printf("findLength(theString) = %d\n",findLength(theString));
    printf("length = %d\n",length);

    return 0;
}

int findLength(char s[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i]!='\0'; ++i){
    }
    return(i);
}
```

---

Just to clarify in your post you have

```
printf("%d",findLength(theString));
printf("%d",length);

printf("%d\n result is",result);
```

Note the `\n` before the `%d` in the last `printf` statement. This is 0 because your `convert` function needs to be fixed and this is the value of `result` **NOT** `length`.

Comment: What is wrong with my printf statements?  I know that they aren't 100% organized but they should still show the correct value right?

Comment: @theBigDream They do show the correct value, I think it is just how they are ordered that has you confused. Currently if you input '324' as mentioned in your question your code outputs `330\nthe result is`. The **0** is from `result` not `length`.

Comment: Oh...I see I'm an idiot I assumed that in my printf statements the number would go after the sentence.